# Making Android apps accessible (for people with disabilities) with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, accessibility

Does anyone have any experience with making an Android app accessible when utilizing PhoneGap? At the very minimum we need to make our apps Section 508-compliant.

I have tried implementing some standard accessibility features (labels for textboxes, adding title attributes to divs, etc). However, when using TalkBack and Expore by Touch in Android, when my PhoneGap app is loaded it just says "WEB CONTENT" - and that's it. Nothing else about my app is spoken aloud.

When the same app runs in iOS with VoiceOver everything works quite well. It reads all of the "title" attributes just fine.

Comment: Which version of Android are you testing with?  Have you enabled web scripts in the accessibility settings?

Comment: Tested with 4.1.1. If you're talking about the "enhance web accessibility" setting - yes - and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I can reproduce that problem as well. It doesn't look like
TalkBack can read things inside the WebView. You should raise an issue
with them:

https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/list

I'm sure we'd be happy to work with them on it.

Comment: What version of Android were you testing on? Web view isn't accessible in anything lower then Android 4.0.

Comment: I finally got around to adding this as an issue: https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=130&sort=-id

Comment: I added a comment to let them know I'd help.