# 508 compliance (users with disability) for android apps made in phone gap

Tags: android, cordova, accessibility, section508

I have created an Android  application using phonegap and now am looking forward to make the application as [508 compliant](http://webaim.org/standards/508/checklist).

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161343/making-android-apps-accessible-for-people-with-disabilities-with-phonegap) post of stackoverflow which has similar grounds but as of now it has no solution, 
I have tried creating a small POC on android version 4.4 for accessibility and on turning the **TalkBack** ON all it does reads the HTML content but fails to read the contents from iFrame.

Can you please hint out on how this can be achieved in Android app build in phonegap.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258379/what-are-usability-accessibility-screen-reader-or-any-other-development-funct